# Duplicate tag [eureka] - synonym of [netflix-eureka]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka) should be made a synonym of [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka). They both refer to service discovery server and client libraries developed by Netflix.

As per [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eureka/info):

> AWS Service registry for resilient mid-tier load balancing and failover.
>   https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/

and [eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka) tag wiki:

> Eureka is a REST service for load balancing on AWS based installations.
>   Eureka at a glance (https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-at-a-glance)

Both are pretty much same. Spring provides Eureka in spring-cloud, but that is (very very) heavily derived from netflix eureka. AFAIK, there is no difference at all.

Questions are also very similar:

- [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka) [Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold)
- [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka) [What's the difference between EnableEurekaClient and EnableDiscoveryClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976236/whats-the-difference-between-enableeurekaclient-and-enablediscoveryclient)
- [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka) [Eureka never unregisters a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616329/eureka-never-unregisters-a-service)
- [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka) [How to config multiple Eureka Servers from client in Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850232/how-to-config-multiple-eureka-servers-from-client-in-spring-cloud)
- [eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka) [Springboot client unable register with Eureka using Docker container id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689202/springboot-client-unable-register-with-eureka-using-docker-container-id)
- [eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka) [Eureka authentication method and UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741236/eureka-authentication-method-and-ui)
- [eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka) [Accessing an internal micro service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943993/accessing-an-internal-micro-service)

Sidenote: I feel the tag description for [nextflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextflix-eureka) needs to be updated to provide a more precise wiki.

Comment: Do note that there is a precise meaning to the word "synonym" in regards to tags. Neither tag is a synonym of the other in this case.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Going by dictionary meaning of synonym, if two tags refer to same technology/library, aren't they synonyms? Am I missing something here? Should I replace [tag:tag-synonyms] tag with [tag:synonym-request]?

Comment: That does seem to be what you are requesting. See also [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710)

Comment: I think I should update the question to request a synonym instead of burnination. [tag:burninate-request] should fail all conditions mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) which is not the case in this question. So I'll update the question.