# Disambiguating the [zuul] tag: API Gateway or JavaScript testing framework

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zuul/info) refers to [a multi-framework for JavaScript browser testing](https://github.com/defunctzombie/zuul).

There is one much more popular library named Zuul: [Zuul is a gateway service that provides dynamic routing, monitoring, resiliency, security and more.](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) It is part of spring cloud package.

There is [netflix-zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-zuul) tag for api gateway library provided by Netflix and used in Spring Cloud.

The issue is **almost all the questions tagged [zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul) are related to netflix api gateway, not the JavaScript testing framework**. Here are 5 highest voted questions tagged [zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul):

- [Netflix-Zuul vs Mashape-Kong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972026/netflix-zuul-vs-mashape-kong)
- [zuul proxy slowness - RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947267/zuul-proxy-slowness-ribbonloadbalancinghttpclient)
- [Overriding zuul error filter results in Forwarding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638647/overriding-zuul-error-filter-results-in-forwarding-error)
- [debug javascript code under test running in the browser using zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573993/debug-javascript-code-under-test-running-in-the-browser-using-zuul)
- [NodeJS Application unable to access from Zuul API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881089/nodejs-application-unable-to-access-from-zuul-api-gateway)

The JavaScript testing framework does not even appear on the first page of Google search results for Zuul. I didn't checked second. Given there are already so many JavaScript frameworks, it's not surprising that it's not a popular framework.

So one of two things can be done:

- Rename [zuul] tag to [javascript-zuul] (or something more precise) to avoid the *unintentional* misuse of tag.
- Burninate [zuul] tag as [netflix-zuul] is already there.

Comment: Request: Please comment for improvement before (or along with) down-voting. Thanks!

Comment: Without being certain whether any of the questions are using zuul correctly, I'd say just rename it.

Comment: Are you the Keymaster?

Comment: [Are you the gatekeeper](https://gph.is/1tfLaIQ)?

Comment: I added a note to the excerpt to hopefully dissuade the handful of people who read tag excerpts from misusing the [zuul] tag. I wouldn't hang my hopes on it fixing all the problems, but it at least limits the problem until a Mod/CM does something about this. In the meantime, it might be worth retagging everything with [netflix-zuul] AND [zuul] to remove the latter tag 54 questions at present)

Comment: Just mentioning it; I finished retagging all questions. Only two of them remain tagged with [tag:zuul]. One of them is about the testing framework, while the other one is unclear, but it's closed and downvoted, so it will be automatically deleted soon. That means that this specific issue is solved so far I guess. I'll check the other Netflix-related tags later.

Answer (score 6):

All questions have been retagged and the [zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul) tag is gone. There were **4 questions** out of the original 144 that didn't have anything to do about the Netflix framework:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371409/apache-not-sending-all-value-in-the-cookie-header-via-proxypass
2. [How to process a git submodule's parent repo with zuul, Gearman and Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984095/how-to-process-a-git-submodules-parent-repo-with-zuul-gearman-and-jenkins)
3. [debug javascript code under test running in the browser using zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573993/debug-javascript-code-under-test-running-in-the-browser-using-zuul)
4. [World of Zuul - adding items using an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790968/world-of-zuul-adding-items-using-an-arraylist)

One of those questions was in a bad shape, and has been closed and deleted thanks to Roomba. The last one was about a game called "World of Zuul", but didn't really need a Zuul-related tag since the problem was pure Java-based.

For the other two tags I created a [openstack-zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-zuul) and [zuul-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul-testing) tag, so that the [zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zuul) tag could be completely disambigued and burninated. This was necessary because new, wrongly tagged, questions were popping up on an almost daily base.

It does seem that the Netflix-related tags need quite some disambiguating after looking at those questions because:

- Some of those questions are tagged with [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) instead of [netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon)
- I also noticed that there is both a [eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka) and [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka) for the same thing

Comment: So if most of [zuul] is mistagged Netflix, then it sounds like we could clean it out fairly simply. I disagree that we should nuke the [zuul] tag solely because it has few questions. Disambiguate the tag and the problem should go away

Comment: @Machavity I would create three separate tags for them in that case, like openstack-zuul, netflix-zuul and zuul-testing.

Comment: @g00glen00b Thanks for taking the pain for fixing the tags but this needs to be fixed properly.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes I have reported the [ribbon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364121/disambiguating-the-ribbon-tag-microsoft-tabs-interface-or-netflix-loadbalance) and [eureka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363884/duplicate-tag-eureka-synonym-of-netflix-eureka) issues. [feign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364087/duplicate-tag-feign-synonym-of-netflix-feign) also has problems.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary That's why I would propose to blacklist [tag:zuul] and create new tags like [tag:openstack-zuul] and [tag:zuul-testing]. That way, the Zuul tag can't be proposed any longer. However, the tag has to be cleaned up anyways, so I'm doing that first since that's something I can do.