# Duplicate tag [feign] - synonym of [netflix-feign]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Having used Feign, I can confidently say that [feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feign), [spring-cloud-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-cloud-feign) and [netflix-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign) refer to the same library.

[feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feign) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/feign/info) :

> Feign is a java to http client binder inspired by Retrofit, JAXRS-2.0, and WebSocket. 
>   Feign's first goal was reducing the complexity of binding Denominator uniformly 
>   to http apis regardless of restfulness.

[netflix-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign) :

> A framework created by Netflix to help connect your code to http APIs.

There are 101 and 188 questions tagged [feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feign) and [netflix-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign) respectively. <s>So [feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feign) tag can be made a synonym of [netflix-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign).</s>

Since community is maintaining the project, [netflix-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign) and [spring-cloud-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-cloud-feign) can be made a synonym of [feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feign) (as suggested by @NH in comments) . [feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feign) should be the master/parent tag.

**Update:**
 Today I noticed that there is a tag named [spring-cloud-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-cloud-feign) also. [Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-cloud-feign/info):

> Use this tag for question related to the use of Feign declarative REST client inside the spring cloud ecosystem.

Seems like people are creating tags without checking alternatives names at all.

Comment: Is it like twitter-bootstrap where these days it's called just bootstrap but it was originally a twitter thing? eg now it's a framework called feign but it was once upon a time Netflix-feign?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The Maven repository name is [`com.netflix.feign`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.feign), but a quick search shows both names being used.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - This is true, but the libraries are all called `feign-core`, `feign-jackson`, etc. It looks like the library is called `feign`, properly.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sounds like [tag:netflix-feign] should be the synonym instead.

Comment: The repository is not even hosted in Netflix's GetHub anymore: https://github.com/Netflix/feign redirects to https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

Comment: @DidierL Feign started as a project by Netflix. Then Netflix moved to Node and and community is maintaining the project since. Yeah I so agree with NH that [tag:netflix-feign] should be synonym.

Comment: I have updated the question to add the point made by @NH.

Comment: There is a tag named [tag:spring-cloud-feign] also.