# Disambiguating the [ribbon] tag: Microsoft Tabs Interface or Netflix loadbalancer

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) tag is being *mis*-used to ask questions that should be tagged [netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon).

[ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ribbon/info):

> A ribbon is an interface wherein a set of toolbars are organized using tabs.

[netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon) [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/netflix-ribbon/info):

> Ribbon is a Inter Process Communication (remote procedure calls) library with built in software load balancers. 
>   The primary usage model involves REST calls with various serialization scheme support.

Newest 5 questions tagged [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) (at the time of posting this question):

- [Spring Ribbon @LoadBalanced doesn't work with @scope(“prototype”) for restTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913657/spring-ribbon-loadbalanced-doesnt-work-with-scopeprototype-for-resttempla)
- [IClientConfig ribbon doesn't read properties from application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901105/iclientconfig-ribbon-doesnt-read-properties-from-application-properties)
- [vba macro list box not letting editing some macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890351/vba-macro-list-box-not-letting-editing-some-macros)
- [Ribbon doesn't see property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889247/ribbon-doesnt-see-property)
- [How to set ServerListRefreshInterval in ribbon load balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885839/how-to-set-serverlistrefreshinterval-in-ribbon-load-balancer)

You can clearly see 4 of the questions are related to [netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon) and and are incorrectly tagged [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon).

To avoid such future conflicts, renaming [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) to  [ribbon-menu] or [ribbon-toolbar] or [ui-ribbon] (or a better rename) is one solution.

If you feel there is a better solution, please suggest.

Comment: In my opinion, [microsoft-ribbon] would be a bad tag name. [ribbon-menu] or [ribbon-toolbar] or [ui-ribbon] would all be better. The ribbon may have been introduced by Microsoft, but is present in many non-Microsoft programs, and is not directly related to Microsoft.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I also feel the same. I've update the question.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  Yep, for instance, DevExpress has it's own Ribbon controls that are also called, well, _"Ribbon"_ :-)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Do you know of any specifc non-MS technologies that use one? (If you do, they should be shot. Ribbon is a horrific UX.)

Comment: Is there a reason to have a ribbon tag which refers to the UI element at all? Does it meet the tag criteria?

Answer (score 7):

As Chris Hayes brought up in the comments:

> Is there a reason to have a ribbon tag which refers to the UI element at all? Does it meet the tag criteria?

I don't believe such a tag, be it suffixed -menu, -ui, -toolbar, etc., meets tag criteria.

Expertise in ribbon menus would indicate the *design* and *user experience*, not the programmatic implementation of them, and we have different sites for design and UX.

Further, a ribbon is a shared menu technique across many applications, and many different companies, on many different platforms. There's no guarantee that when you're talking about a ribbon, you're talking about a specific program, company, or even a specific OS.

I think we should cleanup [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) by retagging to [netflix-ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-ribbon) or similar tags where appropriate, and then burninating the remainder of the [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) uses. If those remaining questions are otherwise on-topic, we can simply edit the questions as needed and remove the tags. If they are not, then we should vote to close them using the appropriate reason.

Comment: It probably would be reasonable to be an expert in the [tag:ms-office-ribbon] tag. Customisation of the ribbon is a common and complex activity for those extending MS Office, however it's a pretty niche thing to have a whole tag for.

Comment: @PaulTurner And [tag:ms-office-ribbon] would be a different tag entirely from [tag:ribbon] in general.

Comment: FYI, if someone starts with retagging, [tag:netflix-ribbon] is related to [tag:netflix-eureka], [tag:netflix-zuul], [tag:spring], [tag:spring-boot] and [tag:hystrix]. So basically if you see a question with those tags, it's a good candidate. I made a SEDE query which I'll use to retag when I have time: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/816479

Answer (score 0):

Since there are quite a few Ribbon-questions, I decided to write a custom query to look for questions with the [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) tag and including either the [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring), [spring-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-cloud), [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot), [netflix-zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-zuul), [eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eureka), [netflix-eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-eureka), [netflix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix), [cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud), [hystrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hystrix) or [netflix-feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-feign) tags. This query can be found [on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/816479/ribbon-cleanup).

From those ~50 questions, I disambiguated most of them, except the following question, which should be closed for asking off-topic questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/36088913

If I understand Roomba correctly, this question should be deleted soon, due to being dead.

While there was a lot discussion about whether or not the [ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon) tag should exist or not, this disambiguation should make it easier to retag if necessary.